# How to write a query to search for info in one column and get the info from all the other columns in that row

Tags: google-sheets

I'm working with Google Sheets. Is there a way to query specific info from a row in column a and get the info in all other columns for the same row?  Not only that, but I would like the info listed in one column even though the original information is placed in multiple columns.  I want to be able to change the search query and the information just populate without having to change the formula.  Here is the formula I am currently using:

```
=IF(A1='Student List'!A2,{'Student List'!B2;'Student List'!C2;'Student List'!D2;'Student List'!E2;'Student List'!F2;'Student List'!G2;'Student List'!H2;'Student List'!I2;'Student List'!J2;'Student List'!K2;'Student List'!L2;'Student List'!M2;'Student List'!N2;'Student List'!O2;'Student List'!P2;'Student List'!Q2})
```

But, this only works if I choose the info from A1, lol.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

try something like:

```
=QUERY('Student List'!A1:Q, "Select B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q where A = '"&A1&"' ",1)
```

Comment: That worked, but is there a way to make the list appear in one column? ie: instead of having it spread to many columns where I have to scroll to see it all and I can't see all the info in one screen it would just go down the rows in one column.

Comment: Do you need ALL the info in the columns ? There are ways to show everything in one column. Can you share an example spreadsheet with some realistic data ?

Comment: I don't need all of the columns, but I do need most of them.  I would need info from columns: B, E-N, & Q to show in the search.  You can see the list on the "Copy of Student Information" Sheet and the formula being used on the "Copy of Individual Classes" Sheet.  I would like all of the info to be listed in columen B on the "Copy of Individual Classes" Sheet instead of being listed in the 1 row.  The column headers don't have to be there as well if that makes it easier.  Thanks!

Comment: Here is the link to the Worksheet I made as an example:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10wirU3SGgxAOXQK6-OYZgH1f-sDPVD6OBLsyyceMxQs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: See sheet JP where I entered: =ArrayFormula(query({'Copy of Student List'!A2:A, 'Copy of Student List'!B2:B&" "&'Copy of Student List'!E2:E&" "&'Copy of Student List'!D2:D&" "&'Copy of Student List'!F2:F&" "&'Copy of Student List'!G2:G&" "&'Copy of Student List'!H2:H&" "&'Copy of Student List'!I2:I&" "&'Copy of Student List'!J2:J&" "&'Copy of Student List'!K2:K&" "&'Copy of Student List'!L2:L&" "&'Copy of Student List'!M2:M&" "&'Copy of Student List'!N2:N&" "&'Copy of Student List'!Q2:Q}, "select Col2 where Col1 = '"&A1&"' "))

Comment: I apologize!  I guess I wasn't specific.  I wanted the info in different rows, but 1 column.  :-(  Any way to do that?

Comment: If the match returns one row, you can easily transpose the query().. =transpose(QUERY('Copy of Student List'!A1:Q, "Select B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q where A = '"&A1&"' ",0)) What if the query returns multiple rows ?

Comment: I have it so that I'm only pulling 1 student at a time.  That's the purpose of the page I am making, so that I can see the info about 1 student at a time.  :-)

Comment: Where would I put that formula you sent to make it work?

Comment: Where you want the output to start ? e.g: if you want it in col C, then C2 maybe ?